# Creating instances of static nested class within that

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

This is related to [Declaring an instance of a class inside that class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023319/declaring-an-instance-of-a-class-inside-that-class)

Why the static inner class Node allows the `new Node[R]` field within the class, and why the infinite recursion is not happening here?

```
public class TrieST<Value> {
   private static final int R = 256;        // extended ASCII


   private Node root;      // root of trie
   private int N;          // number of keys in trie

  // R-way trie node
  private static class Node {
    private Object val;
    private Node[] next = new Node[R];
  }
...
}
```

x = new Node(); // is fine within the containing class, but `new Node[R]` inside static nested Node class is not clear.

Comment: Where do you see a infinite recursion and why should it happen?

Comment: `new Node[]` just initializes the array. It doesn't create `R` Node objects.

Comment: While creating a instance of nested class via `new Node[R]`. I the reason is it's being static then why the construction is allowed via new?

Comment: @Prakhar you don´t create a new instance of a node, you just create a Array of the size 256, with 256 elements beeing null. There is no way where a recursion could happen.

Comment: Side note: "extended ASCII" is not a precise definition of an encoding. If you're trying to represent a specific encoding, you should state what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
private Node[] next = new Node[R];
```

declares and initializes the field `next` which is an *array reference* (you should read `Node[]` as "`Node` array"). The expression `new Node[R]` does not create any node, it creates an array of nodes. So there is no recursion.

If you had a field such as

```
private Node someNode = new Node();
```

then indeed you would have a recursion because each node would create another node that creates a next one, and so on.