# Java GUI ButtonHandler issue

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm not sure what exactly I am doing wrong but I keep getting an error with the ButtonHandler. I have a GUI class and a GUI Test class. The GUI class is the first one and the GUI_Test class is at the bottom. I am using NetBeans IDE 11.0. Everything else works on here but the ButtonHandler. I believe I followed the directions wrong or something because it just keeps telling me to create a new class for the ButtonHandler or break it up. But neither of those things are what I want.
The checkboxes also will not appear in the output text area when you run it.

```
package javaapplication20;


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Week3GUI extends JFrame {`


//variables

private JRadioButton radCoffee, radTea;
private JCheckBox chkFootball, chkBasketball, chkBaseball;
private JTextArea txtMessage;


public Week3GUI()
{
    //instantiate the GUI components
    // this sets 5 rows, 20 columns as default size
    txtMessage = new JTextArea(5,20);


    radCoffee =new JRadioButton("Coffee");
    radTea =new JRadioButton("Tea");


    //instantiate checkboxes
    chkFootball =new JCheckBox("football");
    chkBasketball =new JCheckBox("basketball");
    chkBaseball =new JCheckBox("baseball");


    //create panel for the radio buttons
    JPanel p1 =new JPanel();
    JPanel p2 =new JPanel();

    //set layout for the panel and add the components    
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());      
    p1.add(radCoffee);
    p1.add(radTea);

    // set layout for the panel and add the components
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p2.add(chkFootball);
    p2.add(chkBasketball);
    p2.add(chkBaseball);

    //need to group the buttons together
    ButtonGroup b =new ButtonGroup();
    b.add(radCoffee);
    b.add(radTea);


    //add event handlers for radio buttons
    RBHandler rb =new RBHandler();
    radCoffee.addItemListener(rb);
    radTea.addItemListener(rb);

    //use grid layout for the frame 
    //1 column, multiple rows
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

    //first "row" of the frame is the label
    add(new JLabel("Which do you like?"));

    //next "row" is the panel p1 with radio buttons
    add(p1);

    //third "row" is the textfield
    add(p2);

    // fourth "row" is the textfield
    add(txtMessage);

} //end constructor

    private class RBHandler implements ItemListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
    if(radCoffee.isSelected())
                txtMessage.setText("You like coffee");
    else if(radTea.isSelected())
        txtMessage.setText("You like tea");
        }

    private void processChoices()
    {
            //"read" the radio buttons first
            if(radCoffee.isSelected())
                    txtMessage.setText("You like\ncoffee");
            else if (radTea.isSelected())
    txtMessage.setText("You like\ntea");
            else
            {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Must select a beverage",
                            "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return;  //do NOT continue this method
            }
            //now read the check boxes and APPEND to textarea
            if(chkFootball.isSelected())
                    txtMessage.append("\nfootball");
            if(chkBasketball.isSelected())
                    txtMessage.append("\nbasketball");
            if(chkBaseball.isSelected())
                    txtMessage.append("\nbaseball");
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        ButtonHandler h = new ButtonHandler();
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
        {

            processChoices();
            radCoffee.addActionListener(h);
            radTea.addActionListener(h);
            chkFootball.addActionListener(h);
            chkBaseball.addActionListener(h);
            chkBasketball.addActionListener(h);
        }

    }
 }
 } //end class




package javaapplication20;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Week3GUI_Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Week3GUI g =new Week3GUI();
        g.setSize(300,200);
        g.setVisible(true);
        g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, it is because you create an instance of a ButtonHandler inside of it. I found something related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023319/declaring-an-instance-of-a-class-inside-that-class

Comment: I thought that as well but when you take the instance out, none of it works.

Comment: could you please give link to the example code you mentioned?

Comment: The code is actually not giving me an error now for the ButtonHandler. I don't know what happened. However, I still cannot get the checkboxes to display output onto the textArea. Do you have any input?